# processing hundreds of csv files one row at a time for embedding, upload to pinecone using OpenAI embeddings

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, langchain, pinecone

This is my current code which works for a while and then throws an error of "can't start a new thread."  Tried both threading and multi-processing and both cause this error eventually.

```
def process_file(file_path):
    print(f'file: {file_path}')
    def process_row(row):
    text = row['text']
    row2data = row['row2data']
    year = row['year']
    group_id = row['group_id']
    docs = embedder(text, text, year, group_id)
    my_index = pc_store.from_documents(docs, embeddings, index_name=PINECONE_INDEX_NAME)
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            process_row(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_paths = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
    processes = []

    for file_path in file_paths:
        p = Process(target=process_file, args=(file_path,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 215, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 306, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 329, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/dummy/__init__.py", line 51, in start
    threading.Thread.start(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 971, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

Comment: Can you post a *minimal* `process_row` that causes this issue with a stack trace?

Comment: Edited the original post to include the process row functions.  They are creating embeddings from the text column of each row and then adding the other items as metadata to a pinecone vector db import.

Comment: Your error does not match your code. The error is from `multiprocessing.dummy.pool` which does not show up in your code. The "can't start new thread" error is likely due to starting too many concurrent threads (search `ulimit`). If you are creating a thread pool each in a large process pool, your number of threads will multiply very quickly (past what will likely give a performance benefit I might add).

Comment: I think you are right.  How do I accomplish this multi-processing and just limiting it to 10 processes?  I basically need my code to run against ten separate files at the same time and process them.  That's it.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing more about your processing function where you create the thread pool, but I'd start with using a `multiprocessing.pool` with 10 processes rather than creating a new process for each file.

Comment: That sounds like a solution, can you recommend some sample code that creates a pool of 10 processes so I can avoid this problem?  I ran code earlier that displayed the processes and, you' re right, it was just incrementing to some huge number and then the code predictably failed.

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: @HaiVu What indentation are you referring to?

Comment: The code below `def process_row()`